# How to change default sort order on Mongodb Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

The default is ascending but I need descending, as most of my collection has `createdAt` so they works as logs, and on the top, in the first lines I would see the most relevant ones. How to set this in MongoDB Compass?

Comment: I don't know if you can set that in Compass. Are you using Compass to consume/process the log entries instead of an app? In any case a workaround might be too create a view with the desired sort order and point Compass at it

Comment: I don't think there is a default sort order, but you can specify the field(s) to sort on and the direction.  MongoDB Compass has a `Documents` tab (collection `find` under the hood) and an `Aggregations` tab.  In each you can specify how to sort the documents.

Comment: I do not want to set it, click it, write it always, that is here the pain